# How to remove specific lines in .csv using python?

Tags: excel, pandas

I want to remove specific lines in my .csv file. I am pretty new to python and I am unsure of how to do conditional removal of lines. Following the below example, I want to remove the ***?*abcd and ***?*efgh lines. If line 2 starts with ***?*, I want to remove line 1 and so on. To note, in the actual program, there are way more lines such as this:

```
***?*abcd
***?*efgh
***?*ijkl
abcdefg1
abcdefg2
***?*abcd3
abcdefg3
```

Is there any pandas code I can use to solve this problem? Any links to read up on this will also be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new column with a boolean value to specify the rows to remove. You can use the `startswith()`, `shift()` and `fillna()` methods on the column of your dataframe :

```py
df["condition"] = df.iloc[:,0].str.startswith(r"***?").shift(-1).fillna(False)
```

| index | 0 | condition |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ***?*abcd | true |
| 1 | ***?*efgh | true |
| 2 | ***?*ijkl | false |
| 3 | abcdefg1 | false |
| 4 | abcdefg2 | true |
| 5 | ***?*abcd3 | false |
| 6 | abcdefg3 | false |

The `shift()` method is used to move one row up in the column and the `fillna()` method is used to fill the last value that is empty.
You can remove the rows with this code :

```py
df = df.drop(df[df["condition"]].index)[0]
```